HTTP connection is closing before S3AsyncClient getObject request can complete
I have a Spring Boot application that reads content from an S3 bucket. In my case, I'm trying to perform an MD5 checksum validation on a large file stored in the S3. However, when I try to get the object using an S3AsyncClient, I receive the following exception:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Response had content-length of 2152598993 bytes, but only received 672235520 bytes before the connection was closed.

This is the bean I am using to create my S3AsyncClient
@Bean
public S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient(AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider, String region, String endpoint) throws URISyntaxException {
        SdkAsyncHttpClient nettyHttpClient = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
                .connectionAcquisitionTimeout(Duration.ofHours(3))
                .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofHours(3))
                .readTimeout(Duration.ofHours(3))
                .writeTimeout(Duration.ofHours(3))
                .maxConcurrency(100)
                .build();
        S3AsyncClientBuilder s3AsyncClientBuilder = S3AsyncClient.builder()
                                        .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
                                        .region(Region.of(region))
                                        .httpClient(nettyHttpClient);
        if (endpoint.contains("localhost")) {
            s3AsyncClientBuilder.endpointOverride(new URI(endpoint))
                    .serviceConfiguration(S3Configuration.builder().pathStyleAccessEnabled(true).build());
        }
        return s3AsyncClientBuilder.build();
    }


Here is the code where the exception is thrown:
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(<the name of the bucket>).key(<the file>).build();
CompletableFuture<ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse>> response = s3AsyncClient.getObject(getObjectRequest, AsyncResponseTransformer.toBytes());
ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> responseBytes = response.join();

And this is the full stack trace of the error:
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Response had content-length of 2152598993 bytes, but only received 672235520 bytes before the connection was closed.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.errorAsCompletionException(CompletableFutureUtils.java:65)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.lambda$execute$0(AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:911)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2194)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.lambda$forwardExceptionTo$0(CompletableFutureUtils.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2194)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeAttemptExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:184)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.lambda$attemptExecute$1(AsyncRetryableStage.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2194)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.lambda$forwardExceptionTo$0(CompletableFutureUtils.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2194)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.lambda$execute$0(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:108)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2194)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.completeResponseFuture(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:255)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.lambda$executeHttpRequest$3(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:911)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:482)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Response had content-length of 2152598993 bytes, but only received 672235520 bytes before the connection was closed.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:223)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:218)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:182)
    ... 23 more
    Suppressed: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Request attempt 1 failure: Unable to execute HTTP request: Response had content-length of 2152598993 bytes, but only received 528744448 bytes before the connection was closed.
    Suppressed: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Request attempt 2 failure: Unable to execute HTTP request: Response had content-length of 2152598993 bytes, but only received 721321984 bytes before the connection was closed.
    Suppressed: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Request attempt 3 failure: Unable to execute HTTP request: Response had content-length of 2152598993 bytes, but only received 141983744 bytes before the connection was closed.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Response had content-length of 2152598993 bytes, but only received 672235520 bytes before the connection was closed.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler.validateResponseContentLength(ResponseHandler.java:167)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler.access$700(ResponseHandler.java:77)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler$PublisherAdapter$1.onComplete(ResponseHandler.java:373)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HandlerPublisher.complete(HandlerPublisher.java:447)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HandlerPublisher.channelInactive(HandlerPublisher.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:303)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelInactive(LoggingHandler.java:206)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:303)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:277)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:303)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:418)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:376)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:329)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:221)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:303)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:277)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:303)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:301)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:813)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)

Any help is appreciated.

It may be worthwhile to try a different approach. It seems as though the byte-range isn't being properly updated. Mind trying with AWS CRT as an alternative?
AWS CRT
A starting point Configure AWS CRT

Did you try with custom retry logic that handles partial downloads by re-requesting only the missing parts of the file.
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .key(fileName)
    .range("bytes=672235521-2152598993") // Start from where the download failed
    .build();


@Vescoci I'm trying that approach at the moment. I keep receiving this error, no matter how low I set the target throughput:
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Failed to send the request: Http connection channel shut down due to failure to meet throughput minimum
